# R timeseries sequence of events

Tags: r, time-series, quantitative-finance

Still fairly new to R I've been using R + tydiverse a lot lately to analyse financial (intraday) timeseries data to gather some statistics to help me make trading decisions.

One thing I haven't yet found a good solution in R for is how to test for sequential events.
For example if I want to know the probabilities of event Y happening after X happened and before Z happens (events being values of variables i.e. price hitting a certain value), is there any good library or approach in R to achieve this?

For example if I have a simple

```
tribble(
~t, ~price, ~level1, ~level2, ~level3,
as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 08:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), 5, 6, 8, 0,
as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 09:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), 7, 6, 8, 0,
as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 10:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), 9, 6, 8, 0,
as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 11:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), 0, 6, 8, 0
)
```

and I want to test for `price > level1` **then** `price > level 2` **before** `price <= level3` (true in this data sample), is there a clean way to analyse something like this in R?

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

`lead` and `lag` are super useful for this, check some dplyr explanations here: [Lead and lag.](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html) If you have multiple stocks or want to use intraday-only, `lead` and `lag` respect those if you `group_by(stock)` or `group_by(day)` (once you define those things appropriately. **But**! If your data's missing an hour (e.g., `9:00:00` is missing from your dataset), the lead will skip from `08:00:00` to `10:00:00`, which might not be want you want.

```
df <- tribble(
  ~t, ~price, ~level1, ~level2, ~level3,
  as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 08:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), 5, 6, 8, 0,
  as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 09:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), 7, 6, 8, 0,
  as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 10:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), 9, 6, 8, 0,
  as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 11:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), 0, 6, 8, 0
)
df %>% filter(price > level1 & lead(price) > level2 & lead(price, 2) <= level3)

                  t     price  level1 level2 level3
               <dttm>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2011-03-27 09:00:00     7      6      8      0
```

There are also 'time-aware' tidyverse style package that can help with this (but I don't have much experience): https://business-science.github.io/tibbletime/ and others I can't remember.

Also go through the nycflights part of Hadley Wickham's free online book R4DS: [dates and times](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html) and [model building](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/model-building.html).

Comment: Thank you Jesse for your input! The problem I'm facing with `lead` and `lag` is that I need to know in advance *when* things are going to happen (or by how much I need to lead a variable). For financial timeseries data (I'm working with 1 minute datapoints) I don't know or particularly care in this context when exactly it happens just that the correct sequence is given i.e. level2 is reached before level3 during this day. I'll check out if tibbletime can help here, thanks for the suggestion.